# Why is Dictionary.Add overwriting all items in my dictionary?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a dictionary of type `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>>` and a list of string values. For some reason, every time I do an Add, every value in the dictionary is overwritten. I'm completely stumped as to why this is happening. I made sure it's not a reference problem be declaring and initializing the IEnumberable object within the loop so that it's scope does not go outside one iteration, and it still does it. Here is my code:

```
foreach (string type in typelist)
{
    IEnumerable<string> lst = 
        from row in root.Descendants()
        where row.Attribute("serial").Value.Substring(0, 3).Equals(type)
        select row.Attribute("serial").Value.Substring(3).ToLower();

    serialLists.Add(type, lst);
}
```

where `typelist` is an `IEnumerable<string>`, `root` is an `XElement`, and `serialLists` is my Dictionary.

Comment: You have "closed over the loop variable". Every `lst` you add will be using the *last* `type` variable. Please read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx Interestingly enough, this issue will disappear come C#5!

Comment: I will definitely read over that. Thanks again everyone for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a captured iterator problem.

Try:

```
foreach (string tmp in typelist)
{
   string type = tmp;
```

(and the rest unchanged)

Alternatively, I would evaluate the expression during the add, I.e. do a .ToList() in the .Add:

```
    serialLists.Add(type, lst.ToList());
```

The second option is probably more effective overall, although it does force evaluation of thigs that might otherwise never be needed.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed the problem immediately.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is that your `IEnumerable<string>` sequences are not being populated eagerly, but on-demand, *after* the `foreach` loop would have completed all its iterations. Thus, when any `IEnumerable<string>` sequence is enumerated, the `type` variable would always have the value of the last element in `typelist`.

Here is one easy way to fix it:

```
foreach (string type in typelist)
{
    string typeCaptured = type;

    IEnumerable<string> lst = 
        from row in root.Descendants()
        where row.Attribute("serial").Value.Substring(0, 3).Equals(typeCaptured)
        select row.Attribute("serial").Value.Substring(3).ToLower();

    serialLists.Add(typeCaptured, lst);
}
```